# Using KeyListener with Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, event-handling, keylistener

For a homework assignment I need to create a program that essentially displays a ball and the user should be able to move it using the left and right keys. However, the program isn't responding to the keys. I don't know where the bug is, and I'd appreciate it very much if someone could help! This is the code:

```
public class GraphicsComponent extends JComponent
{
Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 400, 80, 80);

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2.setColor(Color.RED); 
         g2.fill(ball); 
         g2.draw(ball); 
     }

}


public class BallViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //creates a new JFrame called frame

        frame.setSize(600,600); //invokes the method setSize on the implicit parameter frame
        frame.setTitle("Move this Ball"); //sets the title of the fram
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final GraphicsComponent g = new GraphicsComponent(); //creates a new GraphicsComponent called g, is final so that the inner class can access it
        frame.add(g);//adds component g to the frame

        frame.setVisible(true); //sets the visibility of the frame

        class PressListener implements KeyListener //creates an inner class that implements MouseListener interface
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Left key pressed");
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right key pressed");
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
            }
        }

        PressListener listener = new PressListener(); 
        g.addKeyListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`KeyListener` will only respond when the component it's registered is focusable AND has focusable, `JComponent` is not focusable by default.

Instead, use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), they save you all the hassel of messing with focus issues related to `KeyListener`

You're also going to have problems with making the `Ellipse2D` move, start by setting it's position as `0x0` and translating the `Graphics` context to the position you want to paint the ball

As an example...

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");

am.put("up", new DeltaAction(0, -10));
am.put("down", new DeltaAction(0, 10));
am.put("left", new DeltaAction(-10, 0));
am.put("right", new DeltaAction(10, 0));
```

And the `DeltaAction`...`point` is the location at which the `Ellipse` is painted...

```
public class DeltaAction extends AbstractAction {

    private int deltaX;
    private int deltaY;

    public DeltaAction(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.deltaY = deltaY;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        point.x += deltaX;
        point.y += deltaY;

        if (point.x < 0) {
            point.x = 0;
        } else if (point.x + DIAMETER >= getWidth()) {
            point.x = getWidth() - DIAMETER;
        }
        if (point.y < 0) {
            point.y = 0;
        } else if (point.y + DIAMETER >= getHeight()) {
            point.y = getHeight() - DIAMETER;
        }
        repaint();
    }

}
```